# Python error - "Can't find __main__ module" (VSCode)

Tags: python

I am trying to run some example Python code from Universal Robots, found at the bottom of [this page](https://www.universal-robots.com/articles/ur-articles/real-time-data-exchange-rtde-guide/)

I have extracted the files and attempt to run them. However, I keep on getting the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\...\Try> & 
C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe 
c:/Users/user/Downloads/rtde-2.3.6(1)/rtde-2.3.6/example_control_loop.py
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 
'c:/Users/user/Downloads/rtde-2.3.6'
```

I'm rather confused about what this is caused by. I've tried fixes that involve editing launch.json, but none seem to work. Files that I have created myself do not cause this error.

Comment: where is your __main__ module

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked by moving the current working directory into the examples folder:
in terminal cd into `rtde-2.4.8/examples`, than in terminal type for example `python example_control_loop.py`. That will execute the script. Before that, change `ROBOT_HOST` to you robots IP-adress.